# typescript react, dynamic props based on a certain prop value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a React component that can have dynamic props based on a certain prop value, but I stuck in the type declaration...

```js
const layerMap = {
  l1: {
    text: 'l1 text'
  },
  l2: {
    image: 'l2 image'
  }
};

type ElProps<T, K extends keyof T, NK extends keyof T[K]> = {
  layerName: K;
  [P in NK]: T[K][NK];
/* ^^^^^^^^^
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)

A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
*/
  
};

function Elem<
  L extends typeof layerMap,
  LKey extends keyof L,
  LPKey extends keyof L[LKey]
>(props: ElProps<L, LKey, LPKey>) {
  return <h1>element</h1>;
}
```

my goal is to make component `Elem` can be used in this way, generating dynamic props based on passed `layerName`'s value

```js
/* 

when layerName is `l1`, Elem's props will be { layerName: string, text: string; }

when layerName is `l2`, Elem's props will be { layerName: string, image: string; }

 */

const App = (props: any) => (
  <div>
    <Elem layerName="l1" text="text" />
    <Elem layerName="l2" image="image" />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out, by using the intersection type (`&` operator)

[ts playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneAGxQE8koBZFMOAXjgBvKnDjMAjAC5hosXBhIAHjBkBySQuUw1cgL4AaOcwBMMkZXlxQKAOZJ1p6yDtJdluHqp6K1SjDYwJDgAUWYABRwwBgAeABUDOABpOG0kOgATBjgAayQ2CEw4BLgAORS0zOy8gqK4gG0kgF0APgFZD3rw6zoy5oB%20GQbm%20vKm3z04ADJhcXZOUpQQB2TPXypMAFc6DGB6UOYkEBi5ABlUlXSshUCkQrmObl4jD1Ok-IvFKtz8%209OXsSncLvNifK7VX5FU71N75JpUFoACjAUQYMjCkQg0Ri-zgsLYiSBIJaAEoOmIiDBNlBejEABYSFpIQ7LOjwIQorEMAB0rEei2WehiAHoGS0JlQNttdvsAIJgMCIskWClIKk0uCImItORiGJhI4PBZLJD8fCSfBaFRmpSW4U6jx6g14PnG5Zm0yWmz2G12h16%200kiV%20ZSQWBwDJITAoTbMeDysCkIA)

```js
import React from "react";

const layerMap = {
  l1: {
    text: 'l1 text'
  },
  l2: {
    image: 'l2 image'
  }
};

type ElProps<T, K extends keyof T, NK extends keyof T[K]> = {
  [P in NK]?: T[K][NK];
} & { layerName: K };

function Elem<
  L extends typeof layerMap,
  LKey extends keyof L,
  LPKey extends keyof L[LKey]
>(props: ElProps<L, LKey, LPKey>) {
  return <h1>element {props.layerName}</h1>;
}

function App() {
  return (<>
    <Elem layerName="l1" text="x" />
    <Elem layerName="l2" image="x" />
  </>);
}

export default App;
```